# Converting multiple WebMs to MP4

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, mp4, conversion

So, I've been researching how to convert all WebM videos to MP4 in a directory.
I've looked for about half an hour for results, but unfortunately, Google isn't being my
best friend. I found a simple command using ffmpeg to convert a WebM to MP4 in the terminal:

`ffmpeg -i video.webm video.mp4`

This is useful, but I don't want to do this several times when I have 30+ of these in the same directory. Is there a way to do all of it easy with a script?

Comment: Perhaps using Handbrake is easier. You can queue all the files and then just wait for the results.

Comment: If you like `ffmpeg`, try `winff`.

Comment: So I can install it with sudo apt install handbrake? Or do I need to download it somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you loop through all the `*.webm` files using a Bash script?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, which is why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a shellscript:

```
for fname in *webm
  do
   ffmpeg -i $fname $(echo $fname | sed "s/webm/mp4/")
done
```

`for fname in *webm` is a for loop, where the elements that is iterated over is expanded from `*webm`, which will match all files ending in `.webm`

`ffmpeg -i $fname $(echo $fname | sed "s/webm/mp4/")` runs the command for each of the `fname`'s that we aquired for the loop. `$fname` will expand to the current name. `$(echo $fname | sed "s/webm/mp4/")` uses the [stream editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to rewrite `webm` to `mp4`, thus providing the correct filename for the output for `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Please, correct the missing quotes for the two file name parameters of the `ffmpeg` command. Otherwise, the user will have problems with the file names that contain space characters.

Comment: So the MP4s will remain in this same directory right?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't remove them. If you prepend `ffmpeg` with `echo` you can see what will be done step by step.

Comment: @vidarlo Perhaps this would be neater? `for f in *.webm
  do
   ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.webm}.mp4"
done`

Comment: @andrew.46 absolutely. Thanks!

Comment: FedKad is correct, of course.
Why not just edit your code, and make that line look better?:
`ffmpeg -i "$fname" "$(echo $fname | sed "s/webm/mp4/")"`

Comment: @udippel Feel free to edit :) That improvement is well within what anyone can edit; it improves without changing intent :)

Comment: It's me, probably, but I don't like very much when others fiddle with my lines; and I wasn't the first one to point out the problem of filenames including spaces. 
I for one also prefer your version; for a 'askubuntu' your explanation is great. The proposal of andrew.46 might be shorter, neater; though also somewhat more obfuscated.